# Gra’s opinion on tehillim?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, vilna-gaon, kabbalat-shabbat

I heard that the Gra was against Tehillim being stated in public to the point where he would even say that Kabbalat Shabbat should be performed at home? I have two questions on this, number one is obvious, is it true? And number two, with it being true, is it cited/practiced anywhere?

Comment: Are you referring to saying tehillim publicly on shabbos, or any time?

Comment: The shir shel Yom is tehillim

Comment: @Chatzkel It's generally quoted as "he was opposed to adding any extra tehillim to davening beyond shir shel yom" So things like psalm 47 before shofar, psalm 148 before kiddush levana, psalm 67 after counting omer, psalm 27 in elul, psalm 134 before maariv, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA so it’s an issue with adding to davening or public?